# Need assistance with .filter()

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I add curly braces to the filter argument, it does not work?

```js
// Write your code here:

function justCoolStuff(arr1,arr2){

  var newArray = arr1.filter(word => {arr2.includes(word)});
  return newArray

}






const coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'];

const myStuff = [ 'rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway']; 

console.log(justCoolStuff(myStuff, coolStuff))
```

Yet, when I remove the curly braces, the code will run. I thought that it is a function? That should be the right syntax for it or am I mistaken?

```js
// Write your code here:

function justCoolStuff(arr1,arr2){

  var newArray = arr1.filter((word) => arr2.includes(word));
  return newArray

}






const coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'];

const myStuff = [ 'rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway']; 

console.log(justCoolStuff(myStuff, coolStuff))
```

Comment: Please add a proper title to your question. It should explain the issue you have.

Comment: You need to use `return` keyword in order to return a value. If you have arrow function without curly brackets, value which follows the arrow is returned by default. If curly brackets are there, you need to use explicit `return`, like so: `() => { return value; }`

Comment: it's all [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body)

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any reason to use curly braces there? What makes you think that you can randomly use such language features here and there?

Comment: `(word) => arr2.includes(word)` is a shortcut for `(word) => { return arr2.includes(word); }` (notice the **`return`**)

Answer (score 0):

You need return statement
{ return arr2.includes(word)}

Answer (score 0):

When adding curly brackets, the implicit `return` no longer works. You will need to return manually, i.e.:

```
var newArray = arr1.filter(word => { return arr2.includes(word) });
```

Refer to the [basic syntax of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to understand if you format this differently - `var newArray = arr1.filter(word => {arr2.includes(word)});`

```
var newArray = arr1.filter(word => {
  arr2.includes(word)
});
```

If you look at it like that, you're missing your `return` statement.  With parenthesis, the `return` statement is implied.

Answer (score 0):

The use of curly braces after the arrow means the chunk of function code that is to be executed. Therefore, in the first example, you're not returning anything, as you should explicitly say so by using the `return` keyword. On the second example however, when using that syntax, it is understood that you're returning that boolean, which is what the filter method is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Because those get treated as a start of a function and then you implicitly need to return.

But here is some insights on how you can use braces without returning.

```js
// Write your code here:

function justCoolStuff(arr1,arr2) {
    var newArray = arr1.filter(word => {
        return arr2.includes(word);
    });
    return newArray;
}

const coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'];

const myStuff = [ 'rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway']; 

console.log(justCoolStuff(myStuff, coolStuff))
```

Note:

```
function doSomehting() {
  return 1;
}

// is equal to
const doSomething = () => 1;

// also equal to
const doSomething = () => {
  return 1;
}

// but not equal to
const doSomething = () => {
  1
}
```